# Is it OK to ask for proofreading a small text in here?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have just written a short description (a few paragraphs) for a small software project. Not being a native English speaker, I'm looking for a few people to proofread it, correct mistakes and improve style.

Is it OK to ask on this website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how you ask the question.  It would be considered a critique question, which is on-topic, and must conform to our [guidelines](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).  The most important guideline is that you must be asking a specific question about your paragraphs, not just "Please improve my description."  So while our excellent community is likely to improve grammar as well as style, we most of all need to know the *question* you are asking when you come to use for a critique.  Examples might be:

- Does this software project description provide enough detail to interest contributors?
- Is this software project description clear enough to give readers an idea of what the project is about?
- Where does this software project description have grammar errors which might make it sound unprofessional?

The more we know about your goals for the description the better a critique we can provide.

And please, whatever you do, give it a title other than [please critique this](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/can-we-do-anything-to-differentiate-between-various-critique-questions) or something similar.  Make your title descriptive of the question.

Comment: Excellent answer, @justkt.  I'd like to add that it is helpful if we know the intended audience for your material -- we can provide more useful advice if we know who will be reading what you've written.  For example, developer documentation and end-user documentation may have differences in how much explanation is provided for technical terms, while documentation for users of a source-based distro would need information on compile flags that users of a binary distribution would simply find confusing.

Comment: "Proofread" is pretty specific, IMHO. And in theory, it sounds that it'd be on topic. Though I'm uncomfortable with the idea of turning into a proofreading service.