# What is wrong in the following question?

Tags: support

When I want to ask the following, I get 
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
It does not meet our quality standards

> Following English is correct or not?
>
> "You probabily know that there is a huge cyclone in the last two days. Now it is ok. I am fine."

Comment: This seems like the type of thing that would be better [asked in our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel).

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange sites have various filters in place to check new post for warning signs. I can't tell you precisely what tripped you up, but here's the reasons I see that this question wouldn't work here:

- Writers.SE doesn't deal with technical sentence correctness. Proofreading and "is this OK" questions are off topic here (cf. [here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions) and [here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-proofreading-a-small-text-in-here) ).
- Your question is extremely short - just two sentences. Brevity is the soul of wit, but SE questions need context and detail - anything that short is likely to hit the filter.

Comment: Thanks for clrification.