# Can I post my writing for review here?

Tags: support, critique, reviews

> This policy discussion is now out of date. [Critique questions are off-topic on Writers.SE](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writers-se-accept-critique-requests). Please look for more recent posts on this topic.

Would Writers SE be a good place to post a paragraph or two paragraphs of my writing for review?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally yes, [per the /faq](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq) it is allowed so long as you frame the writing and provide enough context for a critique.

See the detailed guidelines at:

[What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/167#167)

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: Please note that this is no longer the case, and [critiques are now off-topic on this site](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/878/26).