# Can I ask this kind of questions here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I just read through FAQ section and I am still not sure if I can ask this kind of questions here or not. What if I am writing a short story and I want to post here one paragraph from it for people to read through it and provide their ideas on how to improve it? Can I do it here or it will be considered an open-ended question that would be closed soon?

If that kind of question is still okay, then I don't understand how I would be presenting several paragraphs here from the same story. For example, I have already asked one such question and named it something like "How would you improve this passage (on peasants' life)?" and posted there one paragraph from my writing about peasants. Let's say I have already received some good answers there. Now let's say I want to present another paragraph from the same piece of writing of mine about peasants, how would I name the next question then? It seems that the title should be just as the one in the previous question, but are we allowed to ask questions with identical titles here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call questions asking for feedback your work critique questions.  They are to be tagged critique as well as other supporting tags.  The guidelines for asking a critique can be found [here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/167/20) on meta.  It is an open-ended question, but our guidelines provide the standards by which it will be judged as "good subjective" instead of "bad subjective."

The guidelines do not permit asking for general proofreading, grammar correction, or just "help fix this!"  They do permit asking a specific question about your paragraph, such as "Does this opening hook the reader?", "Where are the unnecessary words in this paragraph?", "Do I overuse modifiers in this paragraph?", "Does this dialogue ratchet up the tension?", and so many more.

As for posting multiple paragraphs, if the earlier question's feedback is relevant than link it.  Otherwise there need not be a connection between two questions, as they ought to be two distinct questions.

Also note that if you intend to go paragraph by paragraph through the work asking for feedback, even feedback that meets the guidelines, I'd recommend you instead look at [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/internet-communities-where-i-can-read-rate-review-short-fiction-and-post-my-own) and [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/904/what-are-good-places-to-post-your-work-where-it-will-be-read-by-others) which provide places that let you ask for general critiques of your whole work rather than our more stringent guidelines.

Comment: Thank you!!! Now, having read your answer, I think I can give it a try here on writers.se.