# Clarification regarding critical feedback to stories

Tags: discussion, critique

> This policy discussion is now out of date. [Critique questions are off-topic on Writers.SE](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writers-se-accept-critique-requests). Please look for more recent posts on this topic.

I keep hearing that this site has some mechanism by which an author can ask for beta feedback, but I don't see any official mention of it. Is there a clear and easy to follow set of guidelines anywhere that say where authors can post stories asking for feedback, and how that feedback should be given?  If such a post doesn't exist, I think it's of the utmost importance that we refine the rules, make them awesome, and post them clearly where they can be seen.  Without this we have no chance of growing our community, imnsho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag [critique](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) here on meta covers several posts about this. In particular:

- [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)

...which is linked to in our FAQ. Also, we recently revisited some issues around critique questions in these threads:

- [Clarification of critique guidelines](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/clarification-of-critique-guidelines)
- [How are critique questions working out for us?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/how-are-critique-questions-working-out-for-us)
- [Is [critique] a meta-tag?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/is-critique-a-meta-tag)

And this thread on Meta Stack Overflow, the site that discusses the Stack Exchange engine:

- [By posting a selection of previously written text here, are we waiving our copyrights to the excerpt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123501/by-posting-a-selection-of-previously-written-text-here-are-we-waiving-our-copyr)

Comment: I don't see any guideline for length of submission or proper formatting of submission.  In general I would think we don;t want 25 page stories being pasted into a question on our site, but I'd think that's a perfectly acceptable body of words to link to.

Comment: Length: This is true. We discussed it, and decided against being too specific with length. The point is to just post enough of a story that we can get a handle on it.

Comment: What if I would like for someone to read the entire length of my 25 page story and help me with feedback on specific topics?   I understand that I might not get any takers, but is there a prohibition on asking?

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch - That's a really good question; I'd like to know what the community thinks of that. For now, does it make sense to post a regular critique question and link to the story?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. :D

Comment: The problem with a 25 page critique question is that I'd imagine it'd be difficult to come up with a specific question that covers all 25 pages.  But @NathanC.Tresch, you can feel free to prove me wrong!