# On Topic? Evaluating Writing sample for character voice

Tags: discussion

I have a scene that I have been working on and I tend to bounce around on voice.  I can't decide which direction to go...I like both for various reasons.

Would posting the scene and having people take a look be on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Critique questions are on topic here, but as per our critique guidelines you'd need to ask specific questions to avoid it being closed.

- [Official critique guidelines](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/26)
- [Handy flowchart version](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/489/26)

In this case, perhaps asking if character voice has achieved such-and-such a tone would work, or anything else along those lines.

Comment: So would something along the lines of "In this excerpt I have utilized both 1st and 3rd person voice for the same character.  Please evaluate the effectiveness of both voices, which better brings the character to life?"  Something like that?

Comment: I think that'd be good.