# Policy Change: [critique] tag abolished; long live critiques

Tags: discussion, critique

In accordance with discussion at [Is [critique] a meta-tag?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/is-critique-a-meta-tag) , the [critique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) tag is being phased out. Critique questions - i.e. questions asking about your own writing - are still welcome; however, we hope the elimination of the tag will clarify that the critique question needs to be *about* some specific element of writing.