# Can the "critique" tag be burninated, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Stack Exchange employees!

The community has decided that the [critique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) tag is a meta tag that does not describe the content of a question, and should be removed. (Here's [the meta post](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/is-critique-a-meta-tag) about that.) Now that the mods have retagged all questions involving the tag, can the tag be burninated here?

Comment: That does seem reasonable to me.

Comment: I have never seen this Fox Cutter person before. They are a mod here? Where hath they gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no questions with this tag on the main site, and I tried to use it in a new-question form unsuccessfully. It appears this has been attended to. Thanks to whoever did it!